# How can we extract values from a raster and put it in a shapefile?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, geotiff-tiff

I just started using QGIS for a research project and I am not at all familiar with the software nor the formats used. I have a shapefile representing the different departments of France, delimited by borders, and a TIFF file with data points from all over the world that I want to extract and put in the shapefile.

I would like to capture the data from the TIFF file and compute an average for each department (from the shapefile), and put the results in a table (one average data point for each department).

How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to gis.stackexchange!

You are looking for the `Zonal statistics` raster analysis tool:

[image: Zonal statistics]

Under `Raster layer` select your raster, while `Vector layer containing zones` is your departments shapefile :)